# Zend_Validator Question?

Tags: php, zend-framework

how to validate letters and whitespaces using Zend Framework ?

Answer (score 3):

The Zend Framework does have a [Zend_Validate_Alpha](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.alpha) (as well as an [alphanumeric version](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.alnum)).

Normally it doesn't allow white space, but if you pass a `true` into the constructor of the
[Zend_Validate_Alpha](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Validate/Zend_Validate_Alpha.html#__construct) class it will allow whitespace. Same with [Zend_Validate_Alnum](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Validate/Zend_Validate_Alnum.html#__construct).

For example:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Alpha(true); //will allow whitespace and non number letters
```

Answer (score 0):

i think Zend_Validate_Regex is best for this situation

Comment: He'll want to pass in a '/[\w\s]+/i' as his regex in this case.